# How to mark a certain part of the text in watir?

Tags: ruby, watir

Hello is there something that can only mark a certain part of the text?
I can not find the right solution anywhere.

I tried: `double_click`, `flash`, `select_text` didn't work for me.

This works, but this mark everything :  `browser.send_keys [:control, 'a']`

I added picture of example, what i want to do.
Thank you for your answers.
[The red rectangle shows the markings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPO6h.png)

Comment: Can you explain your reasoning for this? There may be other suitable options if we understood the use case.

Comment: [`flash`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir/Watir/Element#flash-instance_method) method might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Imagine, user is on page and he want highlightid part of the text. After highlight, he want to click on bold in ckeditor.
https://ckeditor.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Element#select_text` method. Note that prior to Watir 6.8, you will need to manually include the extension (method).

Here is a working example using the Wikipedia page:

```
require 'watir'
require 'watir/extensions/select_text' # only include this if using Watir 6.7 or prior

browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath')
browser.body.select_text('XPath may be used')
sleep(5) # so that you can see the selection
```

Note that this will highlight the first match. You may want to restrict searching a specific element rather than the entire `body`.

Here is another example using ckeditor.com:

```
require 'watir'
require 'watir/extensions/select_text' # only include this if using Watir 6.7 or prior

browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto('ckeditor.com/')
frame = browser.iframe(class: 'cke_wysiwyg_frame')
frame.p.select_text('Bake the brownies')
browser.link(href: /Bold/).click
sleep(10)
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. My question is what i can do when i can't select text at CKEDITOR.COM and after, i want bold this text ?
I try this: require 'watir'
require 'watir/extensions/select_text' 
browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto('https://ckeditor.com/')
sleep 10
puts browser.element(:xpath, "//body[@class='article-editor cke_editable cke_editable_themed cke_contents_ltr cke_show_borders']/p").select_text('Bake the brownies')
browser.element(:xpath, "//span[@class='cke_toolgroup']//a[@class='cke_button cke_button__bold cke_button_off']").click
sleep(5)

Comment: Why you cannot select the text in the CKEditor is a different problem. The CKEditor uses an `iframe`, which you need to explicitly tell Watir to look into. The answer has been updated with a working example for that page.

Comment: Hi again, thank you for your response. browser.link(href: /Bold/).click  
Is not work for me.
I had to locate CKEDITOR for our country. = browser.link(:xpath, "//span[@class='cke_toolgroup']/a[@title='Tučné (Ctrl+B)']").click
But after that it work well. 
One last question when i used browser.link(href: /Tučné/).click = Console just interupt test. 
So one last question is how to choose only part of text in attribut?
Example: title had text /a[@title='Tučné (Ctrl+B)']")  and i want choose only 'Tučné'.
I hope u know what i mean . Thank you again that was so helpfull!! :)

Comment: Using the Regexp like you did in `browser.link(href: /Tučné/)` is how you would match part of the attribute. If you're asking about in XPath, you can use the `contains` - eg `/a[contains(@title, 'Tučné')]`

Comment: Nice one. Thank you it was helpful